# Convergence of sequence of matrices to identity

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a sequence of invertible real-valued $k\times k$ matrices $\{A_n\}_n$ and another sequence of real-valued $k \times k$ matrices $\{B_n\}_n$ such that $A_n^{-1}B_n \rightarrow I_k$, where $I_k$ is the identity matrix (if it helps, we can also let all of these matrices be symmetric). Let $C$ be a fixed real-valued $q \times k$ matrix (of rank $q$), then is it the case that
$$(CA_nC^t)^{-1}(CB_nC^t) \rightarrow I_q~?$$
Of course if $q =k$ so that $C$ was itself invertible this should follow easily, but I'm not sure how to establish something like this otherwise.

If the above holds, then taking this a step further: if instead we have a sequence of matrices $\{C_n\}$ such that $C_n \rightarrow C$, would it also be the case that
$$(C_nA_nC_n^t)^{-1}(CB_nC^{t}) \rightarrow I_q~?$$